# Not able to connect to Internet when changing from dynamic to static IP in CentoS 7

Tags: networking, ip, centos-7, static-ip, dynamic-ip

I found this issue on various portals but couldn't get any relevant solution.

I have three CentOS VMs (Created on vmware player), let say A,B,C
config of A: Static IP- 192.168.0.110/24 Gateway: 192.168.0.1 
config of B: DHCP (IP: 192.168.73.132, gateway:192.168.73.0)
config of C: DHCP (IP: 192.168.73.135, gateway:192.168.73.0)

if I maintain this configuration then all VMs can ping each other and outside network as well (like google.com)

Now, I want all machines to have static IPs, when i change config of B and C machines, they are not able to ping (not connecting to internet).
I tried giving them various IPs (In range of dynamic 192.168.73.x or 192.168.0.x) but got no luck.

I want my environment like, all VMs have static IP and able to ping each other. Also they can connect to outside world (like google.com).

Note: I am using vmware player with a wifi connection on my host machine.

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you sure that information is correct? Using a gateway of 192.168.73.0 just seems wrong. What virtual network setup are you using for those VMs?

Comment: Hi Seth, Thanks for your response. I got solution for this issue on some post . In my config, VM 'A' was using Bridge Network while other two were using NAT. I switched their network from NAT to bridge connection and bingo !!. It worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In my config, VM 'A' was using Bridge Network while other two VMs were using NAT. I switched their network from NAT to Bridge and it worked.